# What is the use of private constructor in Scala?

Tags: scala

In Java, one of its most common usage is to define a Singleton class. However, since there are no "static" classes in Scala, what are some examples of usages of the Private Constructor?

Comment: 'since there are no "static" classes' What do you mean by that? A Java nested static class can be represented in Scala by defining a class inside a class's companion object (members of companion objects are represented as static members in the generated bytecode), but I don't see what that has to do with the singleton pattern.

Comment: @sepp2k I think, he means 'static' in terms of C# static.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov A static class in the C# sense is a class where all members are static. That also does not apply to singleton classes.

Comment: @sepp2k No, static classes in C# are singletons

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov That's not true. You can't create an instance of a static class nor do static classes themselves act as objects. They're just classes without a constructor whose members are all static. And even if it were true, the interpretation "Scala does not have a built-in concept of singletons (which Java also doesn't have), so, unlike Java, you can't implement the singleton pattern in it" also makes no sense. Not to mention that Scala `object`s actually *are* singletons.

Comment: @sepp2k Who said that singletons should act as objects?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov There are reasons why Java (and C++ etc.) programmers implement the singleton pattern instead of just creating a class where all members are static (and why C# programmers implement the Singleton pattern over using static classes). And these reasons no longer exists if singleton aren't objects. Static classes can't implement interfaces, you can't pass them around and you can't mock them for tests.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can access private constructors in the companion object of a class.

That allows you to create alternative ways of creating a new instance of your class without exposing the internal constructor.

I came up with a very quick example of how one might make use of this:

```
class Foo private(s: String)

object Foo {
  def apply(list: Seq[String]): Foo = {
    new Foo(list.mkString(","))
  }
}
```

Now you can create new instances of `Foo` without the `new` keyword and without exposing the internal constructor, thereby encapsulating the internal implementation.

This can be especially important, as internal implementations might change in the future while the public facing API should remain backwards compatible

Comment: Watch out though, private constructors of case classes still get a corresponding `apply` method. So you can still call `Foo("bar")` in your example.

Comment: Oops, yeah, didn't intend to make it a `case class`, must have happened out of habit :D Edited accordingly :)

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The use cases of the private constructors are mostly the same as in Java: sometimes you need a full control of how the instances of your classes are created. Consider `scala.immutable.Vector`. Its constructor is rather complicated:

```
final class Vector[+A] private(val startIndex: Int, val endIndex: Int, focus: Int)
```

This constructor is a complex implementation detail which is likely to be changed in the future and therefore should not be exposed to users. Instead, you provide simple factory methods which hide all that complexity of creating instances of vectors: `Vector.apply()`, `Vector.tabulate()`, `Vector.fill()`, ...