# What is the practical usage of Private Constructor in Scala

Tags: scala

I have gone through the following links.

[What is the use of private constructor in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765964/what-is-the-use-of-private-constructor-in-scala/42766054)

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-private-primary-constructor-singleton-scala

As per the above link, the problem is given as

> Problem You want to make the primary constructor of a Scala class
>   private, such as to enforce the Singleton pattern.

If I do not want to expose the details of a class, I can still achieve in another way, besides, Object in Scala is Singleton.

Please help me understand the practical usage of private constructor from Scala language view point.

I provide below the code to understand.

```
class Brain private {
  override def toString = "This is the brain."
}

object Brain {
    val brain = new Brain
    def getInstance = brain
}

object SingletonTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val brain = Brain.getInstance
    println(brain)
  }
}
```

I want to understand what is the great thing here so that we have to use private constructor in Scala ?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, is that you can not call `new Brian` in any other place of your code. If you remove the `private`, then you could. Then the **Brian** class would not longer be a singleton *(the companion **object** still would be one)*.
In any case, this is not the best example of why you may want a private constructor, since nobody would encode a singleton in that way, we have `object` for that.

A better example would be something like this:

```
final case class Person private (name: String, age: Int)

object Person {
  /** Returns None if the age is invalid, a Some with a new person otherwise. */
  def apply(name: String, age: Int): Option[Person] =
    if (age > 0 && age < 100) Some(new Person(name, age))
    else None
}
```

This way you can be sure that any instance of **Person** has a valid age.
If the constructor would be let public, this is not longer true, because someone may do `new Person("name", -1)`.

Comment: thanks for reply, I took the example from the link given above. Besides, I can put a validation for age to avoid negative number. My question is more about what is the greatness here to use private constructor. Could you please provide me a real  world example on this ?

Comment: @Sambit haven't I already proven one? How would you handle the above case without a private constructor. How would you ensure that the object can not be instantiated with a negative number.